# Macro to convert many columns in excel from MS to HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

We have a spreadsheet that's being generated by another system that provides data in Milliseconds, but I need to convert it to something that's easier to digest for the business.

I'm looking for an easy way to get it converted to duration **HH:MM:SS** - the columns to be converted aren't always the same columns so I'd need to be able to select certain columns and then do the conversion.

Any help is greatly appreciated - I played a bit with the macros in Excel, but it's been years since I programmed and I wasn't sure how to do some of the relative mappings for the equations.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to divide the whole number 'millisecond' values by 86400000 (1000*60*60*24) then format the cells as hh:mm:ss or hh:mm:ss.000 (the latter retains left over ms).

Comment: Thank you - do you know how I could automate doing this for a bunch of cells using a macro?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a contiguous group of cells containing millisecond values as long integers.
2. Run the convertSelection sub procedure.
3. Select another contiguous group of cells.
4. Go to step 2.

Remember to put this code into a public module code sheet first.

```
    Sub convertSelection()
        With Selection
            .Value = Application.Evaluate(.Address & "/86400000")
            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss.000"
        End With
    End Sub
```